# Repairing Rails and Server and on Nitrous.io

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nitrousio

I was doing One Month Rails's tutorial on Nitrous.io. At one point, some weird files appeared on my tree, and I deleted them. Everything stopped working.

I ran:

```
$ git add .
$ git checkout -f
```

and restored the tree.

BUT, when I ran:

```
$ rails server
```

I get:

```
action@first-project-48185:~/pinteresting$ rails server                                                                                                        
-bash: rails: command not found
```

I also tried:

```
$ ruby -v #and got an older version, so I reinstalled it
$ rails -v

action@first-project-48185:~/pinteresting$ rails -v                                                                                                            
-bash: rails: command not found
```

When I run:

```
$ ruby -v #on MAC terminal, I get the correct version
$ rails -v #on MAC terminal, I get the correct version
```

Interestingly, when I run:

```
$ rails server or $ rails server -p 4000
```

I get:

```
Franciscos-MacBook-Pro:pinteresting franciscomello$ rails server
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
```

and a bunch of other text below:

```
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/franciscomello/Desktop/pinteresting/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Franciscos-MacBook-Pro:pinteresting franciscomello$ rails server -p 4000
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/franciscomello/Desktop/pinteresting/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

What's frustrating is I was on my largest streak without any errors or bugs :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell why Rails is no longer working from those errors, but I would recommend reinstalling rails. Run the following command to reinstall Rails:

```
gem install rails
```

From here you should be able to run `rails server`.

You could also run `bundle install` within the project directory if your `Gemfile` includes other gems which need to be installed.